# How do I generate the range of strings "9811@000000#" - "9811@999999#" using `crunch`?

Tags: command-line

How do I generate the following using `crunch`?

```
9811@000000# 
9811@000001#
9811@000002#
9811@000003#
...
9811@999999#
```

I tried this but it failed:

```
crunch 12 12 1234567890 -t '9811@'@@@@@@# -l 9811@@@@@@@#
```

Comment: @muru why is this off-topic?

Answer (score 2):

From `man crunch`:

```
       -t @,%^
              Specifies a pattern, eg: @@god@@@@ where the only the @'s, ,'s,
              %'s, and ^'s will change.
              @ will insert lower case characters
              , will insert upper case characters
              % will insert numbers
              ^ will insert symbols
```

```
       -l When you use the -t option this option tells crunch  which  symbols
              should  be treated as literals.  This will allow you to use the
              placeholders as letters in the pattern.  The -l  option  should
              be the same length as the -t option.  See example 15.
```

```
       Example 15
       crunch 7 7 -t p@ss,%^ -l a@aaaaa
       crunch  will  now  treat  the  @ symbol as a literal character and not
       replace the character with a uppercase letter.
       this will generate
       p@ssA0!
       p@ssA0@
       p@ssA0#
       p@ssA0$
       <skipped>
       p@ssZ9
```

So you should change in the pattern to `-t`:

- the final `@@@@@@` with `%%%%%%`

and in the pattern to `-l`:

- `9811@` with `@@@@@`
- `@@@@@@` with whatever (say `aaaaaa`)
- `#` with `@`

`1234567890` won't be necessary no more since you won't be replacing characters:

```
crunch 12 12 -t 9811@%%%%%%# -l @@@@@aaaaaa@
```

```
% crunch 12 12 -t 9811@%%%%%%# -l @@@@@aaaaaa@ | head -n 10
Crunch will now generate the following amount of data: 13000000 bytes
12 MB
0 GB
0 TB
0 PB
Crunch will now generate the following number of lines: 1000000 
9811@000000#
9811@000001#
9811@000002#
9811@000003#
9811@000004#
9811@000005#
9811@000006#
9811@000007#
9811@000008#
9811@000009#
```